# Try-Catch inside a "for" loop in c++

Tags: c++

I've  10 numbers to be read. My task is to generate exceptions with the numbers are either a negative number or a even number. Below is the code I wrote, but it isn't working.

```
 #include <iostream>     
 using namespace std;

 int main()
   { 
     int a[10];
     for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        { 
         cin>>a[i];
        }
     for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
          try{
              if(a[i]<0 && a%2==0)
                   throw a[i]; 
             }
          catch(int a)
             {
             cout<<"You ve entered a -ve number or a even number";
             }
   }
    return 0;
    }
```

This was the error shown:

```
In function 'int main()': 16:24: error: invalid operands of types     'int [10]' and 'int' to binary 'operator%'
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What are you trying to do with `a%2==0`?

Comment: Did you actually read the error message? It is quite clear.

Comment: What is the purpose of a try/catch block here? Why can't you just do the `cout` business in the body of the `if` statement? Exceptions should never be used for control flow.

Comment: @CodyGray, and TurboC++ should never by used as a compiler anymore. And yet some institutions don't care.

Comment: @CodyGray it is quite useless, but I can see the educational / fiddling value of exceptions somewhere.

Comment: While that's true, @Story, I don't see anything about Turbo C++ here, and I don't think there is any institution that is forcing Hariharan to misuse exceptions... It is just a common mistake among beginning developers.

Comment: Don't use exceptions for simple logic like this. They are usually *way* slower than a simple `if` or `break`. Exceptions are for exceptional situations (i.e. something that does not normally occur).

Comment: @CodyGray, Sadly misuse of exceptions is taught more commonly than one would care to believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You are modulo-ing an array `a` with an integer `2`. You should dereference it to get the value: `a[i] % 2 == 0`.
2. You do a boolean AND, where you want a boolean OR (according to your question): `||` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

Typo here. You can not do modulo operation on an array. `a%2==0` should be `a[i]%2==0`. Also change `&&` to `||` as you are trying to find "either a negative number `or` a even number".

Comment: FYI there is a close flag for such questions called "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."